# wxpython работает не адекватно

Tags: python, wxpython

Пытаюсь изучать wxPython. Читаю учебник и запускаю **примеры из учебника**. Но в результате получаю нечто похожее, но не совсем то же самое.

Например, изучаю тему "Меню". В учебнике есть пример и есть скриншот его работы:

[image: Так должно быть]

Однако, когда запускаю пример из этого учебника, то вижу вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разница в том, что я не вижу **иконок** и не вижу **символа подчёркивания**. Я не привожу тут исходный текст, так как предполагаю, что дело не в тексте, а в окружении. Я запускал скрипт под Linux Fedora-37 и Python-3.11. Библиотека wxPython4.

Comment: так а в коде есть что-нибудь намекающее на иконки и подчеркнутые символы? Если нет, то это автоматически делается оболочкой на стандартные пункты в меню и все.

Comment: И исправьте заголовок. Во-первых, ничего неадекватного тут нет. Во-вторых, из заголовка должно быть кратко понятно, в чем проблема.

Comment: Приведите текст примера или ссылку на конкретный учебник. Их много...

Comment: @Эникейщик - "ничего неадекватного тут нет." Если программа делает НЕ то, что написано в инструкции, значит она ведёт себя НЕ адекватно инструкции.

Comment: @Эникейщик - "в коде есть что-нибудь намекающее на иконки и подчеркнутые символы?" Безусловно - есть. Например, строка программы *fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_NEW, '&New')* должна отработать так, что появится пункт меню *New*, в котором буква 'N" должна быть подчёркнута. НО этого не происходит.  А иконки в программе задаются вот так: *qmi.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('exit.png'))*. Но эта иконка НЕ  отображается.

Comment: @Chorkov -"Приведите текст примера или ссылку на конкретный учебник.", Вот этот учебник: https://zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/ Раздел с этим примером называется "Submenus and separators". Там полный текст примера приведён.

Comment: если один и тот же код ведет себя "адекватно" на одной системе и "неадекватно" на другой, то очевидно, что проблема "адекватности" не в коде, а в системе. А код как раз ведет себя адекватно.

Answer (score 2):

wxWidgets насколько это возможно, использует элементы управления предоставляемые API операционной системы, а не рисует их сам. (Это коренное отличие от Qt.) Поэтому, поведение и вид окон существенно отличаются на разных операционных системах, а также меняются с обновлением OS, и изменением графической схемы.

Картинки окон с zetcode.com сделаны под Ubuntu (довольно старой).

Клавиатурные подсказки (те самые подчеркнутые символы), вслед за windows, на всех десктопах стали показываться только если вы вызвали мемю клавиатурными операциями. Т.е. если вы кликнули по меню мышью - то подчеркнутых символов нет, а если нажали [alt] или кнопку контекстного меню, то они появятся.

Иконки - вы не устанавливали картинки вручную, поэтому показываются иконки установленные в текущей графической схеме вашей OS, в соответствии с ID пункта меню (wx.ID_EXIT, wx.ID_OPEN...). Просто рисовать иконки в меню стало "не модно". Однако, вы можете нарисовать иконку принудительно, используя `qmi.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('texit.png'))`.

Comment: С символом подчёркивания всё оказалось так, как Вы сказали, а вот иконка на Quit так и не видна.  Хотя никаких сообщений об ошибках нет.